# Mesh find separate component (bodies) within 1 mesh (stackoverflow exception)

Tags: c#, geometry, mesh

What I am trying to do is group separated components (geometries) within my 1 mesh. We have an half-edge data structure. My idea is to grap 1 halfedge and loop through the edges, find paired (twin) half edges and loop through that one to find the faces, if I already visited that face we skip that one and go to the next.

This will result in stackoverflow, because my mesh is too big.

```
public Mesh[] SplitDisjointMeshes()
    {
        var output = new List<Mesh>();
        var visited = new bool[_faces.Count];


        for(var i = 0; i < _halfedges.Count; i++)
        {
            if (visited[_halfedges[i].AdjacentFace]) continue;

            var faces = new List<int>();
            GetDisjointMeshPart(i, ref visited, faces);
            // Todo: Build new mesh from all connected faces
            
        }

        return null;
    }

    private void GetDisjointMeshPart(int i, ref bool[] visited, List<int> faces)
    {
        int he_first, he_current;

        he_first = i;
        he_current = he_first;

        do
        {
            he_current = _halfedges[he_current].NextHalfedge;

            var tmp = _halfedges.GetPairHalfedge(he_current);

            var face = _halfedges[tmp].AdjacentFace;

            if (face == -1 || visited[face]) continue; // Not found or aready visited
            faces.Add(face);
            visited[face] = true;
            GetDisjointMeshPart(tmp, ref visited, faces);
        }
        while (he_current != he_first);
    }
```

Any ideas on how to resolve the stackoverflow from happening? Or if it is possible to get an O(N) loop.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I follow the logic, but it looks like every single face will call `GetDisjointMeshPart` (recursively) as long as it hasn't been visited. I feel like you should also check `visited` before the `do` loop in case something happens between an earlier call and later. In any case, you can re-write any recursive call as a queue/stack which will at least solve your stack overflow but probably you will still have some astronomical runtime to resolve.

Comment: @BurnsBA thank you for the tip, I had searched for days to find a solution. And luckily I also found a queue solution which I now implemented to queue up next faces which seems to work!